# View did load or View Finished Loading does not run when switching between views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I am using a custom Switch view controller and you would hope when switching between different views the "view did load" function or "view did finished loading" functions run but they do not. 
Here what I am using:

```
- (IBAction)gotoKeyboardViews:(id)sender
{

YellowViewController *yellowController =
[[YellowViewController alloc]
 initWithNibName:@"YellowViewController"
 bundle:nil];

self.yellowViewController = yellowController;
[yellowController release];
[buttonKeyboard removeFromSuperview];

buttonStart = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
buttonStart.frame = CGRectMake(117,413, 103, 37);


[buttonStart setTitle:@"Restart" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonStart addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoBlueView:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:buttonStart];
[blueViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view insertSubview:yellowViewController.view atIndex:0];  
}
```

gotoKeyboardViews suppose to switch the views To YellowView From BlueView...But I think I am a little bit off about implementing the navbar. Please don't tell me to go with the navbar because I don't like their rigidness in design.

Comment: Those methods aren't always called, this is normal behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewWillAppear` method is executed as soon as the view gets active again. Maybe that's the hook you are searching?

Reference: [Apple UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear%3a)

Answer (score 0):

those methods are only called when the nib file is loaded or the if you've override loadView. They will not get called again unless a new view controller is instantiated.